# Julia pipe operator works with function involving multiplication but not with exponentiation

Tags: julia, pipeline

The following code works fine:

```
f(x) = 2*x
[1, 2, 3] |> f
```

However, the following code fails:

```
g(x) = x^2
[1, 2, 3] |> g

Closest candidates are:
  ^(::Union{AbstractChar, AbstractString}, ::Integer) at strings/basic.jl:718
  ^(::Complex{var"#s79"} where var"#s79"<:AbstractFloat, ::Integer) at complex.jl:818
  ^(::Complex{var"#s79"} where var"#s79"<:Integer, ::Integer) at complex.jl:820
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion
   @ ./none:0 [inlined]
 [2] literal_pow
   @ ./none:0 [inlined]
 [3] g(x::Vector{Int64})
   @ Main ./REPL[17]:1
 [4] |>(x::Vector{Int64}, f::typeof(g))
   @ Base ./operators.jl:858
 [5] top-level scope
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not related to the pipe operator at all:

```
julia> [1, 2, 3] * 2
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 4
 6

julia> [1, 2, 3] ^ 2
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching ^(::Vector{Int64}, ::Int64)
```

If you want to apply an operation on every element in a container you should use [broadcasting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting) (see also https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots/)

```
julia> [1, 2, 3] .* 2
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 4
 6

julia> [1, 2, 3] .^ 2
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 4
 9
```

The fact that `[1, 2, 3] * 2` works is because vector times scalar is a mathematical operation whereas vector raised to a scalar (`[1, 2, 3] ^ 2`) is not.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense and be more idiomatic to broadcast the pipe operator? At a minimum, it should be mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @fredrikekre 's answer, I would like to mention that the following works:

```
g(x) = x^2
[1, 2, 3] .|> g
```

Adding an extra dot for broadcasting does the trick and allows using the pipe operator thereby feeding collections to pipes and getting collections out.

Another way to get the broadcast operator have effect on the entire pipe is to use the `@.` macro:

```
f(x) = 2x
g(x) = x^2
@. [1, 2, 3] |> f |> g
```

Comment: I believe in 1.6 you can even do `[1,2,3] |> .g`.

Comment: @phipsgabler It fails with `ERROR: syntax: invalid identifier name "."`. I am using julia version 1.6.0.